# How can I inject a named component into a sub-graph in Dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

so I'm working on a project using Dagger 2 in Android. I have two objects that are scoped `@Singletons` of the same type, so I've used the `@Named("some name")` annotation to distinguish the two, But I'm trying to expose these two objects to the sub-graphs, such as `@PerActivity`, but am not able to think of a simple way of doing that. usually when I want to expose a sub component it's easy... just add it to my `ApplicationComponent` interface, but in this case I don't know how to do that sense both components are of the same type. Is there a clean way of doing this? or am I going about it wrong? any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@Named("some name")` annotation in both your modules **and** your components. Which means that if you specify the two provision methods with different names but the same return type with the added annotation, you should be able to expose both to the subgraph.

Comment: you're saying I can do @Named("some name") in the component interface?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that before and it worked (added it both to module and component).

Comment: Excellent! I'll try it out. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct by using `@Named("NAME_GOES_HERE")` to have 2 singletons of the same type.

```
class ExpensiveCoffeeMaker {
  @Inject @Named("water") Heater waterHeater;
  @Inject @Named("hot plate") Heater hotPlateHeater;
  ...
}
```

Source: http://google.github.io/dagger/

Be sure that when you are injecting these things you include the `@Named("YOUR_NAME_GOES_HERE")` annotation as well.

I haven't used the `@PerActivity` annotation that you mentioned; I've only used a single graph in my projects.  Why do you need an injection per activity anyways?  Can't you just maintain state within that activity and use the injected dagger component globally with the local state data you are keep within the activity?

Comment: @PerActivity is a custom scoping annotation that I wrote, though it's a petty common one in Android DI, but you can name it anything. The point of it, is that you can add a reference to your current activity in that scope, and never have to worry about if that activity no longer exists, sense activities have a different life cycle than your application. It's guaranteed to exist when ever you are using that scoping. So in my case I use it for the MVP pattern... in my presenters I can reference the current activity without having to do a check for activity == null or whatever.

Comment: because I'm trying to reference those named scopes in a sub scope (ie @PerActivity) as far as I can tell there's no way to do it. at this point I've just made a custom object to hold them instead, but down the road, if I can find a cleaner solution, I'll change that. I can, however reference them when ever I'm in the @Singleton scope.